# When does $|\hat{f}(n)|$ decrease to $0$ monotonically; while $\hat{f}(n)$s are Fourier coefficients of $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

With attention to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Uniform_convergence) we know:

> If $f$ is $2\pi$ periodic and absolutely continuous on $[0,2\pi]$, then the Fourier series of $f$ converges uniformly

Now if we show the Fourier series of $f$ like this:

\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(n)e^{i 2\pi t \frac{n}{T}}
\end{align}

Then *Cauchy condition* for a uniform convergence Fourier series implies:
\begin{align*}
    \forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists n \in \mathbb{N} : |\hat{f}(n)| < \epsilon
\end{align*}
which means $\hat{f}(n) \to 0$ uniformly.

Now my question is: If Fourier series of $f$ converges to $f$ uniformly, then when does $|\hat{f}(n)|$ decrease to $0$ monotonically? That means:

\begin{align}
    \forall n \in \mathbb{N} : |\hat{f}(n+1)| \leq |\hat{f}(n)|
\end{align}

Comment: I don't think there's a good characterization for that. For instance you could make the reverse: take a monotonically decreasing series $a_n \to 0$ and define $f := \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb N} a_n e^{i2\pi t\frac{n}{T}}$

Comment: @LucasHenrique I want to know "If Fourier series of $f$ converges to $f$ uniformly, then under which conditions does |f^(n)| decrease to 0 monotonically?"

Comment: I would think monotonic convergence is very special.  In many cases, some of the $a_n$ are equal to $0$.

Comment: Yes, even analytic functions do not satisfy things like that